# A question on Jordan blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $J=\operatorname{diag}\left(  J\left(  \mu_{1}\right)  ,\ldots,J\left(  \mu_{r}\right)
\right)  $ be a Jordan matrix of dimension $n\times n$ with Jordan blocks

$$J(  \mu_{i})  = \left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cccc}%
\mu_{i} & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \mu_{i} & \ddots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \mu_{i}%
\end{array}
\right)  \in \mathbb{C}^{n_{i}\times n_{i}}$$

Let $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{r}\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda
_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{r}\notin\sigma\left(  J\right)  $, (where $\sigma\left(
J\right)  $ stands for the spectrum of $J$). Let define the vector $w=e_{n_{1}}+e_{n_{1}+n_{2}}+\cdots+e_{n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r}}$
where $e_{i}$ represents a vector of the standard basis with entry $1$ at
position $i$. (In fact $e_{n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots+n_{k}}$ is a generator of the
cyclic subspace associated with $J\left(  \mu_{k}\right)  $).

Let define the set $\mathcal{S}$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S}  & =\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{r}\mathcal{S}_{i}\\
\mathcal{S}_{i}  & =\left\{  \left(  J-\lambda_{i}I\right)  ^{-j}%
w:j=1,\ldots,n_{i}\right\}
\end{align*}
Prove that $\mathcal{S}_{0}\subset\mathcal{S}$ such that $\operatorname{card}\left(
\mathcal{S}_{0}\right)  =n$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: Presumably, $n_k = \dim J(\mu_k)$ for each $k=1, \ldots, r$?

Comment: Never mind.  I see it in your definition of $J(\mu_i)$.